# How to overwrite object state in redux reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a ScrollView in react-native that is used for notifications, based on a fetch.  The objects are properly connected to the store, and the fetch/dispatch properly update the store.  On first pull, everything populates correctly and in the right order.

On the second fetch, however, the state.notifications isn't getting replaced with the new value.  Instead, it adds it all together, with many fields being duplicated.  Initially this was done as just a fetch, but I wanted to be able to update it from other screens, so switched it to a redux call.

I'm fairly new to both redux and react-native, but can't seem to find a solution to completely overwrite the store so that the ScrollView is not retaining previous items.  It needs to be a complete overwrite, because a fetch may show that items have been removed, or altered, not just added.

My reducer is super simple, and looks like this:

```
export const notificationData = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATENOTIFICATIONS': 
      return (state = action.val);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The dispatch is simple as well, and completes properly within a fetch response (albeit adding to existing data):

```
store.dispatch({
     type: 'UPDATENOTIFICATIONS',
     val: responseJson.notifications
});
```

responseJson.notifications is an array of notifications that looks like so:

```
[{ 
  notificationid: 440,
  postid: 145,
  commentid: 374,
  notificationtime: '2018-01-11T00:00:00.697Z',
  isread: true,
  <some other field>
},{
 ...
}]
```

I'm guessing I am missing a very basic detail here, but how do I get a dispatch to overwrite the state for an object rather than append to it?

Everything I have found so far seems to focus on deduplication, merging, etc. (with the idea your list would be getting added to, but no deletions occur) But all I want is a simple overwrite, since notifications can be deleted, marked as read, etc.

Is this doable somehow?

Comment: I see two weird things. 1) your initial state is `0` ? empty array probably seems more appropriate. 2) `return (state = action.val);` <-- you're modifying state here, which might be messing with things. in redux you should not be mutating stuff ever just return directly the next state `return action.val;`

Comment: also to answer your general question "is this doable"? yes absolutely. basically every use-case imaginable is doable unless your trying to build a time machine

Comment: @azium I think you are onto something with the state=action.val

On further testing, it occurs after I call another dispatch elsewhere which either decrements state or sets it to 0.  I don't think I understood the state modification issue thoroughly.  I'm exploring the "Object.assign" methods now that I know to look for it.  I will go through all my other reducers to make sure I haven't mangled the state.  Thanks for that!

Comment: sure.. yeah don't overthink it. just remember that a reducer should only be responsible for one "piece of state" meaning not to mix different parts of your app state in a single reducer. use `combineReducers` with multiple reducers for that. and always return new state (the next state) in reducer function

Comment: Ok, so I corrected everything such that it is no longer altering state.  I replaced the call of state = val with: 

export const notificationData = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATENOTIFICATIONS':
      return Object.assign([], state, action.val);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

Again, everything still works fine on first call.  But when I refresh and call the fetch / dispatch from the Main screen, the ScrollView on the Notifications tab still gets populated with loads of duplicates.

Comment: can you please update your question with the latest code? also It's probably a good idea to post the connected component and the component that displays the data. I would also make sure that `responseJson.notifications` doesn't contain duplicates itself since if it does that's obviously where the issue is

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I went back through, got a more thorough understanding of the intended process, and cleaned everything up.  For now, the trick in place is to push an extra dispatch to reset notifications to '[ ]' .  It works, if clunky, but is so far the only fix I found.  It's a pretty big set of code, so would be hard to share here.  Thanks for the tips though, as that pushed me to go through with a fine tooth.